# Microsoft Bot - Authenticate exposed API endpoint (IDX10205: Issuer validation failed)

Tags: azure, authentication, authorization, botframework

Trying to add authentication/authorization to an exposed endpoint by a Microsoft Teams Bot.
The bot is deployed on Azure; bot-things working fine so far.

It's exposing 2 endpoints:

- `/api/messages`:  this is used as BOT URL.
- **`/api/notify`**: this is the endpoint I want to add authentication & authorization.

***Context***: the Bot is exposing `/api/notify` so an external service will call here making the bot to send activities to public channels.

#### Azure Configuration overall

The Bot Channel Registration is linked to a registered app on the Active Directory. This registered app has a will-never-expire secret. The src code itself uses this `applicationId` and `secretId`.

#### What I've tried

- **App service > Authentication**: App Service Authentication ON/Login with Azure Active Directory

  - ClientId: the `applicationId`
  - Issuer URL: **`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}`**
- **Authentication tab**: I've added a Web platform:

  - https://{my-service}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback
- **Supported account types**: Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)
- **Enable Implicit Grant flow** > Open ID tokens
- not sure if I need to "Expose an API" and set as Application URI the base URL of the bot service (https://{my-service}.azurewebsites.net);
- not sure if I need to register a second app in the Active Directory and have a tuple: "bot app"/"authentication provider" and re-think the whole thing

In the end, I want the external service to authenticate using a pair "clientId/clientSecret" and making HTTP requests to {my-service}.azurewebsites.net/api/notify;

- no token -> 401
- valid token -> ok

#### The problem

With this configuration the bot stops authenticating itself, if I - for instance - open the emulator and use the original `applicationId + secret` credentials, the initial POST to `/api/messages` receives:

```
{
  "value": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer: '[PII is hidden]'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidIssuer: ..."
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to authenticate when the Web API is called, I think you would want something like this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-nodejs-webapi) that demonstrates "how to protect a Node.js web API with Azure AD B2C using the Passport.js library". The method you use above is more for logging a user in _while_ the user is actively using the bot (i.e. a login prompt is displayed to the user which is clicked and starts the authentication process).